# A templated constructor cursor and a templated member cursor have kind FUNCTION_TEMPLATE in libclang

Tags: python, c++, llvm, abstract-syntax-tree, libclang

### Some context

I am not that familiar with libclang. I am just modifying a vim plugin which uses [the python bindings to libclang](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/tree/master/bindings/python).

There is a python function which receives a cursor parameter. This is called for almost every node in the AST of the current C++ buffer.

### The problem

`cursor.kind` is used to get the kind of the cursor. All is ok, except that

- templated free function declarations,
- templated constructor declarations and
- templated method declarations

all have the same kind: `FUNCTION_TEMPLATE`. I need to differentiate between them.

### More insight

For instance, the non-templated versions of the above have the kinds:

- `FUNCTION_DECL`
- `CXX_METHOD` and
- `CONSTRUCTOR`.

I have search the source of [cindex.py](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/clang/blob/master/bindings/python/clang/cindex.py) and there are no `CXX_METHOD_TEMPLATE` or `CONSTRUCTOR_TEMPLATE` or similar.

I have tried without success to somehow get the information I need, e.g. with `cursor.get_definition()` and `cursor.underlying_typedef_type.get_declaration()`.

The only partial success I got is that for a method and a constructor the semantic and lexical parent is a `STRUCT_DECL`.

I don't really care if it's templated or not. All I care if it's a constructor, member or free function.

### To sum it up

Given a cursor, how I can tell if it's a method (even templated), a constructor (even templated) or a free function declaration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr

```
cindex.CursorKind.from_id(cindex.conf.lib.clang_getTemplateCursorKind(cursor))
```

---

Browsing the [C libclang online doxygen documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX.html) we find in the [C++ AST introspection](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CPP.html) the function [clang_getTemplateCursorKind](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/group__CINDEX__CPP.html#gafe1f32ddd935c20f0f455d47c05ec5ab)

> ```
> CINDEX_LINKAGE enum CXCursorKind  clang_getTemplateCursorKind (CXCursor C)
> ```
>
> Given a cursor that represents a template, determine the cursor kind
>   of the specializations would be generated by instantiating the
>   template.

Which is exactly what I want. Unfortunately, calling it in Python is not as simple.

By looking around, this is how we call the `C` functions not implemented explicitly in Python:

```
tk = cindex.conf.lib.clang_getTemplateCursorKind(cursor)
```

Don't ask, black magic.

The next bump in the road is that this function returns a long. If we really want the `CursorKind` object, we need this:

```
cindex.CursorKind.from_id(tk)
```